# AttributeError: __exit__ when trying to use arcpy.UpdateCursor

Tags: arcpy, cursor, update

I'm trying to populate a field from values of an existing field in a feature class using arcpy.UpdateCursor.

I'm getting this error:     `AttributeError: __exit__`

Here's the chunk of code I'm using:

```
with arcpy.UpdateCursor(polyline, ["SEWER_TYPE"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row.getValue("Layer") == "FUTURE_STORM":
            row.setValue("SEWER_TYPE", "STORM")
            cursor.updateRow(row)
del row, cursor
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not need to delete the row/cursor objects when using the `with` statement, this will automatically clean up when `__exit__` is called after the cursor has exhausted itself.

Also, it is easier to reference the fields by index because the rows are returned as tuples:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(polyline, ["SEWER_TYPE", "Layer"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[1] == "FUTURE_STORM":
            row[0] = "STORM"
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Because you are using the with statement, I am assuming you are using at least ArcGIS 10.1 or beyond?  If not, maybe that is why you are getting an attribute area because it does not have the `__exit__` method.  In this case, do not use a `with` statement:

```
cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(polyline)
for row in cursor:
    if row.getValue("Layer") == "FUTURE_STORM":
        row.setValue("SEWER_TYPE", "STORM")
        cursor.updateRow(row)
del row, cursor
```

Comment: Thanks a so much ! Really appreciate it! It works! I'm using 10.2 and I got some conflicting info on which update cursor to use (arcy.da.UpdateCursor vs arcpy.UpdateCursor). Thanks again!